# Highcharts show all categories even when no data

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am working with high charts, I have a set of controls on a web page that allows the user to select months and locations.  The issue is if they select a location that has no data.  So lets say they select January and Hawaii but there is no data for Hawaii in January.  Nothing will be displayed at all, but I would like the axis to appear along with the labels.

NOTE:  I am trying to create a heatmap so I don't want to see the minimun color when there is no data.

Comment: Have you tried supplying a value of 0 when there is no data?

Comment: I updated my question so which may explain why setting to zero wouldn't work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A value of null seems to work. You can change your tooltip to not display if the value is null too: http://jsfiddle.net/SheldonNeilson/95um4x0q/1/

```
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/heatmap.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<div id="container" style="height: 400px; min-width: 310px; max-width: 800px; margin: 0 auto"></div>

$(function () {

    $('#container').highcharts({

        chart: {
            type: 'heatmap',
            marginTop: 40,
            marginBottom: 80
        },


        title: {
            text: 'Sales per employee per weekday'
        },

        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Alexander', 'Marie', 'Maximilian', 'Sophia', 'Lukas', 'Maria', 'Leon', 'Anna', 'Tim', 'Laura']
        },

        yAxis: {
            categories: ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday'],
            title: null
        },

        colorAxis: {
            min: 0,
            minColor: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0],
            maxColor: '#FFFFFF'
        },

        legend: {
            align: 'right',
            layout: 'vertical',
            margin: 0,
            verticalAlign: 'top',
            y: 25,
            symbolHeight: 280
        },

        tooltip: {
            formatter: function () {
                if(this.point.value == null){
                 return 'No data'  ;
                }else{
                return '<b>' + this.series.xAxis.categories[this.point.x] + '</b> sold <br><b>' +
                    this.point.value + '</b> items on <br><b>' + this.series.yAxis.categories[this.point.y] + '</b>';
                }
            }
        },

        series: [{
            name: 'Sales per employee',
            borderWidth: 1,
            data: [[0, 0, null], [0, 1, 19], [0, 2, 8], [0, 3, 24], [0, 4, 67], [1, 0, 92], [1, 1, 58], [1, 2, 78], [1, 3, 117], [1, 4, 48], [2, 0, 35], [2, 1, 15], [2, 2, 123], [2, 3, 64], [2, 4, 52], [3, 0, 72], [3, 1, 132], [3, 2, 114], [3, 3, 19], [3, 4, 16], [4, 0, 38], [4, 1, 5], [4, 2, 8], [4, 3, 117], [4, 4, 115], [5, 0, 88], [5, 1, 32], [5, 2, 12], [5, 3, 6], [5, 4, 120], [6, 0, 13], [6, 1, 44], [6, 2, 88], [6, 3, 98], [6, 4, 96], [7, 0, 31], [7, 1, 1], [7, 2, 82], [7, 3, 32], [7, 4, 30], [8, 0, 85], [8, 1, 97], [8, 2, 123], [8, 3, 64], [8, 4, 84], [9, 0, 47], [9, 1, 114], [9, 2, 31], [9, 3, 48], [9, 4, 91]],
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                color: '#000000'
            }
        }]

    });
});
```